# Filter that affects all pages in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC

Tags: c#, html, filter, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I am creating a Recipe Blog Website in ASP.NET Core 7. I want to create a filter for my recipe category (eg: All recipes, Veg recipes or NonVeg recipes) on my website navbar so that it can affect all the pages at once for the ease of user experience. Here is my code-

`FilterController.cs`:

```cs
public class FilterController : Controller
{
     private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

     public FilterController(ApplicationDbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index(PostCategory? postCategory)
     {
         var post = from p in _context.Posts select p;

         // Category Dropdown
         if (postCategory != null)
         {
             post = _context.Posts.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory);
         }

         return View(await post.ToListAsync());
     }
}
```

`_TopNavbar.cshtml`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 ps-10 fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!--Options-->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between ps-3">

            <!-- Dropdown -->
            <div class="col-4">
                <form asp-controller="Filter" asp-action="Index" id="category">
                    <select class="form-control" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<PostCategory>()" name="postCategory" id="post-filter">
                        <option value="">All</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" asp-area="" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Index">Reset</a>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's related with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457695/i-want-to-create-a-dropdown-filter-for-my-post-categories-on-index-page-using-an)?

You could try to store posts with  [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

a minimal example:

```
public class FilterController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public FilterController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _context = context;
        _cache = cache;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(PostCategory? postCategory)
    {
        List<Post> posts;
        if (postCategory != null)
        {
            posts = _context.Post.Where(c => c.PostCategory == postCategory).ToList();

        }
        else
        {
            
            posts = _context.Post.ToList();

        }
        _cache.Set("posts", posts);
        return View(posts);
    }
}
```

In post controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var cached = _cache.TryGetValue("posts", out var posts);
    if (cached)
    {
        return View(posts);
    }
    return View(await _context.Post.ToListAsync());
}
```

Now the result:
[image]

If your posts would be updated frequently or you just want to know PostCategory ,you could  store `postCategory`in cache

Update:
You could  try convert the enum to string and store it in cache:

```
 var selected = postCategory.ToString();
 _cache.Set("Selected", selected);
 var selectedincache = _cache.Get("Selected") as string;
 
var postCategoryfromcache = Enum.Parse(typeof(PostCategory), selectedincache);
```

Comment: How to retain the dropdown value selected?

Comment: Hi,@ ZNAXNOR,You could convert the enum to string/int when you store it in cache(convert it to string makes more sence),I've updated the related codes,hopes help

Answer (score 0):

FilterViewModel to store the selected category:

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public PostCategory? SelectedCategory { get; set; }
}
```

You have to modify the  FilterController to handle GET and POST request. get cam help retrieve selected category from ViewModel.

```
public class FilterController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public FilterController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new FilterViewModel
        {
            SelectedCategory = null 
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(FilterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // You can access the selected category as viewModel.SelectedCategory
        // Perform filtering logic here based on the selected category
        // Update the ViewModel with the filtered results

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

_TopNavbar.cshtml:

```
<form asp-controller="Filter" asp-action="Index" id="category" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="SelectedCategory" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<PostCategory>()" name="SelectedCategory" id="post-filter">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success me-2" type="submit">Search</button>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" asp-area="" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Index">Reset</a>
</form>
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@{
    var filterViewModel = ViewBag.FilterViewModel as FilterViewModel;
}
```